# Handling a reoccurring event in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was looking at ways to implement logic for reoccurring events. I would like to display events for the upcoming week, dependent upon their recurrence.

For example I have 2 events, one is weekly and the other is two weekly, In my view for this week I would only show the one event, but come next week there would be two showing.

So far I have my models set up like so in the migration file ready to be created

```
class CreateEvent
  create_table :events do |t|
   t.string :title
   t.text :description
   t.time :time_from
   t.time :time_to
   t.date :next_date
   t.string :day
   t.timestamps null: false
 end 
end
# An Event `has_one` Frequency

class CreateFrequency
  create_table :frequencies do |f|
    f.string :occurs
    f.integer :event_id
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
# Was Thinking of pre populating this with Weekly and 2 weekly
# A frequency `belongs_to` Event
```

I am trying to keep this as simple as possible, so would I need to implement some kind of logic where I would do a calculation starting with the Events `next_date` and counting the weeks passed up to today's. Not quite sure here.

Could I even go down the route of having a flag in the event model, a column called `display` (boolean) and have a Rake task that will update it again using the next_date? Would that work? I am unsure of the logic there, mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the frequency in the event table, (1 for every week, 2 for every two weeks) and then use some math to figure out if the upcoming week is an even amount of weeks after the original date, something like this:

```
Event.where("(extract(week from NOW())::int - extract(week from time_from)::int) % 2 = 1 OR frequency = 1")
```

This should grab all events that are either in its "2 week cycle" next week, or has its frequency set to 1.

**Note:** This will work for postgres at least, but you would need to change the data type to datetime instead of just time.

If you already have next_date stored for the events, then you can use a time range to select all events in the upcoming week:

```
start_date = Date.today.beginning_of_week + 7.days
end_date = start_date + 6.
@events = Event.where(next_date: start_date..end_date)
```

**Note**: 
I read "upcoming week" as "next week", you'd have to modify it at bit if you wish for a different behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it out and see how it goes :-)

Comment: ok so at the moment i get an error `PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  "time" units "week" not recognized`.. would this be because of `time_from`, i use this to store a time (15:00) and i use a time_to (18:00), the value stored in the field though looks like so `January 01, 2000 18:18`, the jan 01 is always present for every record that is saved ??

Comment: Ah, yes, makes sense. You would need a data type containing an actual date to be able to extract the week from it. Changing it to timestamp should solve the problem. Or if you don'w want to change time_from/time_to you could add a t.datetime :first_occurrence_at or something like that. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you store the original date of the event in the database, and calculate the next event inside your model.

```
def frequency
  case occurs
  when 'weekly'
    1.week
  when 'biweekly'
    2.week
  end
end

def next_event  
  event_no = ((Time.now-first_event)/frequency).floor+1
  return first_event +  event_no*frequency
end

def event_next_week?
  next_event < Time.now+1.week
end
```

To avoid having to do calculations every time user requests a list of events you can have a CRON job or some other sort of recurring job that would calculate the dates of next events at the beginning of each week and save them to database.

Rather than as a string, you could store the frequency as number of days or weeks.

Keeping a variable 'display' would be troublesome if you want to display events for the next 7 days and you want to stop displaying an event once it ends. Date is more flexible:

```
@events = Event.where('next_event > ? AND next_event < ?', Time.now, Time.now+7.days)
```